# AS3 bitmap width vs draw shape (Performance)

Tags: performance, actionscript-3

Just a quick question, which way render quicker:

i would like to have a background set up (a sprite);

method 1

```
sprite.graphic.draw()
sprite.graphic.drawRect(0,0,100, 1024)
```

method 2: a png (original height 10px) and just make the height to 1024

```
sprite.addChild(Bitmap);
Bitmap.height = 1024;
```

Thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with the previous "performance" question, always best to test.  My background knowledge (pun totally intended), tells me that the first method is better, in the second method you have to load the PNG decode it, scale it, in the first method you simply modify the pixels in memory that you need (can cache the Sprite using cacheAsBitmap).

More on cacheAsBitmap here: http://www.andymoore.ca/2010/09/cacheasbitmap-performance-testing/

**Edit**
Per comments, a better solution

```
var bd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(100, 1024, false, 0xff00ff00);
var bmp:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bd);
addChild(bmp);
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#BitmapData()

Comment: Another possibility is to create a BitmapData from scratch and fill it with a floodFill

Comment: again good call Ms. Blankenship most likely a better solution to just get right to the BitmapData.